# How to replace @media (max-width) using Stylish or Greasemonkey?

Tags: css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, stylish

I'm having a problem viewing [this website](http://www.fleaflicker.com/nfl/) on my desktop browser. They have a responsive/fluid design that shows a mobile menu button instead of a horizontal nav-bar when the browser width is less than 990px.

Since I'm using Firefox with 125% zoom, my desktop browser is less than 990px effective width.

I looked into the CSS code and found the line. How can I use Stylish, Greasemonkey, or some other way to automatically replace the max-width value of "990px" with "800px"?

```
@media (max-width:990px) { ... }
```

I'm using Firefox 23 on Windows 7.

Edit: Based on comments so far, I need to replace their CSS file with my own custom CSS file. So how do I use Greasemonkey to replace the `href` (which appears to be a non-static filename)?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://d1h60c43tcq0zx.cloudfront.net/static/css/versioned/global-cdn-ac243f54ab6bb9637fcc5fa32f8b514d.css"></link>
```

Comment: An overly invasive way to solve this would be to edit your host file and use a local version of their css that has a better width restriction for you.

Comment: You can't do a replacement like this using those extensions as far as I know. You can only write your own set of styles to overwrite it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to:

1. Find the offending `<link>` using the constant part of the text in the `href`.
2. Record that link's `href`.
3. Delete that link.
4. Use `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` to fetch the file again (hopefully it's cached).
5. Use regex to fix the fetched CSS.
6. Use `GM_addStyle()` to add the fixed CSS.

Here's **a complete Greasemonkey script** that illustrates the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Replace bad CSS link
// @include  http://www.fleaflicker.com/nfl/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var badCSS  = $("link[href*='global-cdn-']");
var badURL  = badCSS.attr ("href");

badCSS.remove ();

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "GET",
    url:        badURL,
    onload:     function (rsp){
        var betterCSS   = rsp.responseText.replace (
            /max-width:990px/g, "max-width:500px"
        );

        GM_addStyle (betterCSS);
    }
} );
```

---

Notes:

1. For faster/better performance, if the CSS does not change often, hand edit it and save it in the same folder that you install your script from.  Then use `GM getResourceText()` to get the CSS, instead of `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`.
2. If page "flicker is an annoyance, due to start-up delays, that is a whole other problem, that can *probably* be solved with `@run-at document-start` and mutation observers.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Amazing that it could dynamically replace the 990px with 800px, that way it will work even when the source CSS changes. I didn't even notice any flickering either. orz

Comment: great answer.. unfortunately it only applies to greasemonkey/FF, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182275/how-to-override-media-max-width-using-stylish) is a similar question specifically for stylish/chrome

Comment: @abbood, This does work on Chrome with Tampermonkey.  Might look at your specific case in a few days. (I'm busy, no promises.)

Comment: @BrockAdams Did you get this to work with Chrome and Tampermonkey somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you add Stylish to Firefox, you can add styles for a specific domain. I usually find that I need to include `!important` with many styles to get them recognised.

Another option for Firefox is to edit the userContent.css file directly. You can easily google "userContent.css firefox windows7" to find its location. (I use a Mac.)

Comment: I don't think it's that practical for my case because 1) There are ~50 elements within the @media block. 2) I can't simply append an `!important` after each one because I need to eliminate the property. So I would need to look up what the original value for every property, then add `!important` to that.