# how to override @media (max-width) using stylish

Tags: css, stylish

## Intro

this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927101/how-to-replace-media-max-width-using-stylish-or-greasemonkey) but unfortunately the answer only applies to greasmonkey (which only works on firefox). Further, this was asked on the stylish forum but the [answer](https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/44708/css3-media-query-unsupported) was ambiguous.

## Question

I want to remove the left column in the [azure help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) and 
expand the main body to make it cover the widht of the screen.
The first part can easily be done by this

```
#sidebarContent {display:none}
```

How ever the second part must conver this

```
media (max-width: 1199.99999px)
```

to this

```
media (max-width: 100%)
```

But I have no idea how to do that using stylish.. ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [override a media query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792163/8157693) you just need to load another media query - *that also applies to your device* - **after it**.

Well...you want a blunt media query that applies to everything. The best way is to use `@media (min-width: 1px)` since that **includes all devices**.

<s>Now, put it all together - along with some other CSS cleanups like `padding` and `margin` removal and setting a new `width` for `.mainContainer` and you get this</s>

```
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1px) {
    .mainContainer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100vw;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body>.container {
    padding: 0;
}
}
```

New code: *(with different selector for width)*

```
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1px) {
    .mainContainer { /*example styles*/
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    body>.container {
    padding: 0;
}
    body>.mainContainer>main {
    max-width: 100vw!important;

}
}
```

*You still have to adjust the padding to your preference as setting the padding to 0 breaks the design a little bit but this should be good starting point.*

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: there are still margins on the side.. i need it to cover 100% width of the screen..

Comment: as i advertised for it here > https://userstyles.org/styles/145425/azure-help-expander

Comment: the above can be achieved if i manually override max-width to 100% but using chrome devtools.. rather than stylish itself

Comment: @abbood I edited the answer. You have to find the right selectors to override and then add them to the media query I put in the answer. My answer is not about finding the selectors, it's about **how to override the default media queries**.